# How to reverse a Path object?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics

I have created an arch from a path object like this:

```
path.addArc(rect, 0f, -180f) //and this draws my path CCW. 

//and if i wanted it drawn CW:
path.addArc(rect, -180f, 180f)//reverse
```

but i wish i did not have to do this. i wish there  was a function like:
path.reverse().

I noice there is a [path directions class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Direction):   but i dont see how to use it  with Arc.... any idea how i can reverse a path better ?

Comment: `Specifies how closed shapes (e.g. rects, ovals) are oriented when they are added to a path.` - Directions are only used when adding closed shapes. Anything else needs to be done manually. What exactly is your use case? Why would you want to reverse the whole path?

Comment: I'm showing animation path. Sometimes I want it reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of revert the arc, you could reverse the step counter of your animation...

pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(yourArcPath, false);

```
  Matrix mxTransform = new Matrix();
    float eachStepLen = pathMeasure.getLength() / 200; //200 animation steps
    if (currentStep <= 110 && !reverseActive) {

        currentStep ++; // --- Going forward...

        pathMeasure.getMatrix(
                eachStepLen * currentStep,
                mxTransform,
                PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG);

        canvas.drawBitmap(image, mxTransform, null);


    } else {
        reverseActive = true;

        pathMeasure.getMatrix(
                eachStepLen * currentStep,
                mxTransform,
                PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG);

        canvas.drawBitmap(image, mxTransform, null);

        currentStep --; // --- Going backwards...

        if (currentStep == 0){
            reverseActive = !reverseActive;
        }

    }
```